# Management resource on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Are there any services that can plot a graph that show the dependecies between the AWS components ?

Imagine that I have a SQS that is subscribe in SNS. And a Lambda register in the same SNS. Is there anyway to see these dependecies?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could think would be using Terraform (https://www.terraform.io) - honestly I never tried it but sharing some ideas on the table.

Ideally you already managed your infrastructure using such a tool (or it could be Cloudformation) but as you dont mention any of it, I'll assume you dont.

Terraform will have an [import](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/website/source/docs/commands/import.html.md) command so you can point it to your resource and it will generate state file.

Using those state file, you can generate a [graph](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/graph.html) of your infrastructure described in those state files.

If you were using Cloudformation, I have found a [github project](https://github.com/benbc/cloud-formation-viz). It uses the same [graph lib](http://www.graphviz.org/) so the render will be about the same. The project is not heavily maintained though so I am not sure it will know about recent services